# Computing the integral of $\int \frac{25x^2}{(x+3)(x-2)^2}\,dx$

Tags: integration

How would I find the indefinite integral of the expression
$$
\int \frac{25x^2}{(x+3)(x-2)^2}\,dx
$$
I have tried using impartial differentiation but was unsuccessful.

Comment: what is "impartial differentiation" ?

Comment: The standard integration technique here uses [partial fractions](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/partialfracdirectory/PartialFrac.html).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use partial fraction decomposition:

$$\dfrac {25x^2}{(x+3)(x-2)^2} = \frac{A}{x+3} + \frac B{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2}$$

Now, solve for $A, B, C$.